# Deploy osx apps on Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, electron, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

is it possible to deploy osx apps using Gitlab CI ? Default Gitlab is running on linux but what I would like to get is build electron app for osx. It is possible only on osx system.

Thanks for help.
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab currently offers only shared linux runners for free. Unfortunately, there is no way to build electron app for osx using Gitlab CI.

Gitlab is currently working to make shared macOS runners available. You can track the progress here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/gl-infra/infrastructure/issues/5720